# Generations in garbage collection and Large object heap

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, garbage-collection

I am aware that we have generations 0, 1 and 2 in garbage collection but how is it related to Small object Heap (SOH) and Large object Heap(LOH)? Does the generation concept applies to SOH only? If so, when are the objects in LOH collected?

Comment: LOH are GCed together with Generation 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how is it related to Small object Heap (SOH) and Large object
>   Heap(LOH)

Only the SOH is seperated into generations. The LOH isn't.

> Does the generation concept applies to SOH only?

Yes.

> If so, when are the objects in LOH collected?

Once a gen-2 or LOH memory threshold is met, and a collection to one of them is required. If a gen-0 or gen-1 collection is requested, it won't collect the LOH.

I suggest reading [Large Object Heap Uncovered](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx#id0070017) by Maoni Stephans which walks you through the internals of the LOH.

Comment: *it won't collect the LOH.* This I didn't know... Do you have a quote/link? Is it only limited to "some" GC types? (concurrent, server, ...)

Comment: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx#id0070017) *"Now let's see about collection costs. LOH and generation 2 are collected together. If either one's threshold is exceeded, a generation 2 collection will be triggered."*

Comment: Ah ok... It isn't a special effect of being a LOH... It is more like "if now I'm collecting gen0 or gen1, I don't do gen2, so I don't GC LOH"

Comment: @xanatos Yes. That's the way the algorithm works AFAIK.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - Thank you for answering this! The link "Large Object Heap Uncovered" doesn't seem to work, but I could find lot of details by searching with Maoni Stephans.. Thank you again!